# Files encrypted in a folder - how to reverse it?

Tags: encryption

I've been playing with a computer game (Kerbal Space Program, OS X 10.9.3) and recently found that I can no longer load saved games (missions). I contacted the tech support and all they could say is that the folder containing the saved game files is encrypted. What is more,  I can create a new game but once I quit, I can no longer load it. It seems that something keeps encrypting the files in that particular folder. Why is this happening and what can I do about it? How can I reverse the encryption?

Comment: Which OSX version are you running? Do you have any utilities installed which do directory encryption?

Comment: Scusi, OS X 10.9.3. I don't remember installing such utilities.

Comment: OSX has no built in folder encryption. Are you storing the save files in DMG or on an external drive?

Comment: No, it resides in the application folder. I appreciate your help and patience, thanks!

Comment: Can you check file permissions (`cmd-i` in Finder)

Comment: The privileges are set to read&write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be due to ACLs. You can clear the ACLs on the folder recursively with:

```
chmod -R -N /path/to/folder
```

Comment: It did work, I managed to load the file nut once I quit the game and launched it again, had the same problem. As if something keeps encrypting that folder. It's maddening.